# Книги упражнений и решений на php

Tags: php, книги

Какие книги есть, где можно практиковаться на php? Написание скриптов от простых до трудных. Спасибо.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по PHP](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/458485/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Книга - **Головоломки на PHP для хакера (+ CD-ROM)**
Книга разбита на две части: непосредственно задачник и ответы на задачи, следующие в конце книги. Вы может решать все задачи последовательно или, если перед вами стоят срочные задачи защиты сайта, может воспользоваться готовыми кодами, которые будут поставляться на компакт диске.

ИМХО для новичка и для практики пойдет!

Answer (score 0):

Таких книг не встречал. Лучшая практика, это поставить себе задачу, например, написать гостевую книгу, попытаться её реализовать и параллельно обращаться к документации. Потом, когда всё заработает, оптимизировать то что сделано :)

Answer (score 0):

Так же учись на примере других скриптов, хорошая практика по разбору стороннего кода.